# Excel VBA Password Protection check

Tags: excel, password-protection, vba

I have a project in which I have to go over 1,000+ excel files in a folder, and see which ones are password protected and which ones aren't. In order to save time, I wrote a macro to do this, which is as follows:

```
    Sub CheckWbook()
     Dim Value As String, a As Single,  myfolder as string
     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Show
        myfolder = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
     End With
     Range("C4") = myfolder
     Range("B7:C" & Rows.Count) = ""
     a = 0
     Value = Dir(myfolder)
     Do Until Value = ""
        If Value = "." Or Value = ".." Then
        Else
            If Right(Value, 3) = "xls" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsx" Or Right(Value, 4) = "xlsm" Then
                On Error Resume Next
                Workbooks.Open Filename:=myfolder & Value, Password:="zzzzzzzzzzzz"
                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Range("C7").Offset(a, 0).Value = "Yes"
                End If
                Workbooks(Value).Close False
                On Error GoTo 0
                Range("B7").Offset(a, 0).Value = Value
                a = a + 1
             End If
End If
Value = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

The problem I'm having is that the popup for the password is still present: it does not fill in the password. Any help would be highly appreciated. -A

**Edit**
Changed the code a bit, and got past the error message, but now I'm getting stuck at the password popup, that stops the macro from completely working, despite the On Error Resume Next feature.

Then, I came across this code that I thought could help:

```
    Option Explicit

Public Sub ProcessBatch()

Dim strFileName As String
Dim strFilePath As String
Dim oDoc As Document

' Set Directory for Batch Process
strFilePath = "C:\Test\"

' Get Name of First .doc File from Directory
strFileName = Dir$(strFilePath & "*.doc")


While Len(strFileName) <> 0

    ' Set Error Handler
    On Error Resume Next
           
    ' Attempt to Open the Document
    Set oDoc = Documents.Open( _
               FileName:=strFilePath & strFileName, _
               PasswordDocument:="?#nonsense@$")
   
    Select Case Err.Number
        Case 0
            ' Document was Successfully Opened
            Debug.Print strFileName & " was processed."

        Case 5408
            ' Document is Password-protected and was NOT Opened
            Debug.Print strFileName & " is password-protected " & _
                "and was NOT processed."
            ' Clear Error Object and Disable Error Handler
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
            ' Get Next Document
            GoTo GetNextDoc

        Case Else
            ' Another Error Occurred
            MsgBox Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description
    End Select
   
    ' Disable Error Handler
    On Error GoTo 0
   
    '-------------------------------------
    '-------------------------------------
    '---Perform Action on Document Here---
    '-------------------------------------
    '-------------------------------------
   
    ' Close Document
    oDoc.Close
   
    ' Clear Object Variable
    Set oDoc = Nothing
   
GetNextDoc:
   
    ' Get Next Document from Specified Directory
    strFileName = Dir$()

Wend

End Sub
```

but this fails to recognize the oDoc as a Document. Any ideas on how to get it working?

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` does not work, as discovered by the OP. One approach would be to send a WM_CLOSE message to the popup dialog: Use SendMessage in the windows API to do that. But not easy to engineer into your code. Another approach *could* be to code the above in VBScript, taking care to keep the Excel.Application object's visibility state to False. I've never tried that so can't guarantee that the popup dialog will not display.

Comment: It's strange, I've tried your macro it work perfectly fine. So the problem not in macro itself , but in something esle. Could you describe more precisely, when the issue apears, in which iteration... As a non related tip, I would reccomend using option Application.ScreenUpdating = False which can improve productivity of your macro.

Answer (score 0):

to open the excel file? or sheet

if it is a sheet should be

ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password: = "yourpassword"

if it is an excel

ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect("youtpassword")

I hope it serves you a hug I learned a lot here I hope you will also hopefully serve my help

Comment: i don't want to unprotect the file, just see if the files are password protected or not. Thanks for the tip anyways!